# opendj data replication for new base dn for multi-tenancy

Tags: opendj

For OpenDJ multi-tenancy, we usually have two options:
1. create a new base dn for a new tenant
2. create a new base dn (with a new backend) for a new tenant.

The thing is for the dsreplication, suppose I have a opendj-srv-1, and opendj-srv-2 which are configured as data replication.

My question is when I create a new tenant, which means a new base dn is created ? does that mean for the newly created base dn, I have to the dsreplication enalbe/initialize stuff for the new base dn ?

or the newly created base dn can be automatically data replicated ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean 1. create a new base dn in an existing backend 2. create a new base dn in a new backend ?

Comment: for example, for a new tenant abcd, I might choose to
1. create a new backend and a new basedn, dc=abcd
2. create a new basedn with existing backend, dc=abcd

Do I need to do dsreplication for the new basedn dc=abcd ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `dsreplication enable` followed by `dsreplication initialize` is required for replicating a baseDN.